# Homology of smooth loop spaces of spheres

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm looking for a reference on the homology of $C^\infty(S^1,S^n)$. So far I've only been able to find references for spaces of maps which are $C^k$ or in a Sobolev class. I also have references which show that $C^0(S^1,S^n)$ and $C^k(S^1,S^n)$ are homotopy equivalent, and I'm wondering if this is still true for $k=\infty$.

Comment: Do you know if $C^{\infty}(S^1,S^n)\cong\displaystyle\lim_{\leftarrow}(C^{k}(S^1,S^n),i_k)$ where $i_k\colon C^{k+1}(S^1,S^n)\to C^{k}(S^1,S^n)$ is inclusion? Also, does $C^{k}(S^1,S^n)$ retract onto $C^{k+1}(S^1,S^n)$?